# How can I setup test data for functional testing in Grails?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, integration-testing, functional-testing, spock

So we have a restful service that we want to test using a restclient in grails.

The test code should go something like this...

```
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

def setup() {
  this.dbEntity = new DbEntity("someid123").save();
}

void "Test entity GET"{
        given:
            RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()

        when: "The DB entity service is hit"
            RestResponse restResponse = rest.post("http://localhost:8080/api/someentity/$id");

        then: "A 200 error is sent"
            restResponse.status == 200


}
```

The problem I am having is the setup method blows up on .save() because there is not hibernate session.  How can I manipulate my database before running a test?

Comment: Are you tried to add in test "setup:" block?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method named like "setupData", and call it in the "given" block of "Test entity GET" testcase.

```
def setupData() { this.dbEntity = new DbEntity("someid123").save(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load some data before each funcional test, you can create a helper class, with @Shared variables or methods or both. Even you could override the setup, setupSpec methods in that class.

Your first class does not extends Specification now, DataLoader class (helper class) instead.

```
class MyControllerSpec extends DataLoader {

    void setup(){
        createEntity()
    }


    void "Test entity GET"{
            given:
                RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()

            when: "The DB entity service is hit"
                RestResponse restResponse = rest.post("http://localhost:8080/api/someentity/$dbEntity.id");

            then: "A 200 error is sent"
                restResponse.status == 200

    }
}
```

And your helper class is the one which extends Specification, with its methods and @Shared variables.

```
import spock.lang.Shared

class DataLoader extends Specification {

    @Shared DbEntity dbEntity

    void createEntity(){
        dbEntity = new DbEntity("someid123").save();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When extending `GebSpec` in Grails 2.5.6, none of the other answers helped: I would still get

> Method on class [...] was used outside of a Grails application

on the `save()` call.

Adding `@TestFor(DbEntity)` to the test class helped.

NB: While that annotation breaks integration tests, it seems to be necessary here. Not sure why that is.

Comment: This only kind-of works if you have _one_ type you need to do this with, and cleanup isn't really possible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `remote-control` plugin. In Grails 2.x, add this to your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
repositories {
    ...
    mavenRepo "http://dl.bintray.com/alkemist/maven/"
}

plugins {
    ...
    test ":remote-control:2.0"
}
```

After refreshing dependencies and potentially adjusting some settings (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35176827/539599) and [here](https://github.com/ldaley/grails-remote-control#testing-applications-with-catch-all-url-mappings)), you can use it like so in tests:

```
// <project>/test/functional/<package>/MyControllerSpec.groovy
class MyControllerSpec extends GebSpec {

    RemoteControl remote        

    DbEntity dbEntity

    def setup() {
        this.remote = new RemoteControl()           

        this.dbEntity = remote {
            new DbEntity("someid123").save()
        }
    }

    def cleanup() {
        remote {
            DbEntity.findAll().each { dbe ->
                println("Deleting $dbe")
                dbe.delete()
            }
        }
    }
```

Note:

- You can invoke `remote` in `given`/`setup` and `when` blocks as well.
- Sometimes, it seems to be necessary to wrap core in `remote { ... }` in a `DbEntity.withTransaction { ... }`. Maybe that's obvious for the more intitiated; I stumbled over that.
- If you want to return a `DbEntity` from `remote` it must be serializable.